# Replacing values of an array based on values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map, array-filter

I have the following array type

```
export const images = [
  { id: "000012", label: "night sky", cost: "35" },
  { id: "000013", label: "country road", cost: "16" },
  { id: "000014", label: "baseball game", cost: "12" },
  { id: "000015", label: "horse racing", cost: "24" },
  { id: "000016", label: "bike gathering", cost: "18" },
  ...
  { id: "001138", label: "kite surfing", cost: "25" },
```

and also have the following 2nd array

```
const product = [
  { product: "000013" },
  { product: "000016" },
  ...
]
```

and I'd like to replace the values of my product array with the label's value of my first array. The second array holds the id value of the first array in the product property.
Expected outcome would be:

```
const product = [
  { product: "country road" },
  { product: "bike gathering" },
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i ran a loop through each `product` and then find the corresponding `image` for it. And finally updated the `product` value with the `image label`.

```js
const images = [
  { id: "000012", label: "night sky", cost: "35" },
  { id: "000013", label: "country road", cost: "16" },
  { id: "000014", label: "baseball game", cost: "12" },
  { id: "000015", label: "horse racing", cost: "24" },
  { id: "000016", label: "bike gathering", cost: "18" },
  { id: "001138", label: "kite surfing", cost: "25" },
]

const products = [
  { product: "000012" },
  { product: "000013" },
  { product: "000014" },
  
]

products.forEach((p, index) => {
    const image = images.find(({id}) => id === p.product);
    if(image) {
      const newVal = {product: image.label};
      products[index] = {...p, ...newVal};
    }
})

console.log(products)
```